# post request using python for multiple json body

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to post requests to a url with input body as a dict, here's the sample code

```
import requests
json_ = [{"foo":"bar"},{"foo1":"bar1"},{"foo2":"bar2"}]
for i in json_:
    r = requests.post(url, json=i,auth=auth)
    print(r.text)
```

but i have around 20k dict bodies, and using for loop takes lot of time,is there any way i can get the request content by passing all json_ in a single POST ?

Comment: That would depend on the server, if the form only allows single entities then no if they allow batch processing then yes just submit it all.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the API you're posting to. If it only accepts a single object at a time, no.

You could split the job between threads and speed up the progress a lot that way. You can split up the list in some five lists and make a function that does the post. Then, make a thread for each list, start them and join them.

https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/